# I have purchased Dacor gas stove for high altitude by mistake. I have same size for 20 years. How I can convert to low altitude 200 ft

Tags: stove

I have purchased Dacor gas stove for high altitude by mistake. I have same size for 20 years.  How I can convert to low altitude 200 ft.

Comment: What model is said stove?

Comment: I think the orifices will have to be changed from the high altitude set to low altitude. Is the fuel natural gas or LPG, aka propane?

Comment: Does this range have a gas oven or electric oven? There will be one orifice for each burner and one or two for a gas oven.

Answer (score 5):

Contact Dacor.  If it is possible to convert it would be by purchasing a conversion kit from Dacor and following the instructions that come with it.